# Primefaces 3.5 Editor save content

Tags: primefaces, editor

Could anyone give me an idea as to how I could save the content in the Editor on button click and store it as a text file?

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: To save what content? To save the text file server side or client side? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

got the content by use of the following code:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("saved: " + getEditorContents()));
```